# Haproxy deny domain and path with map

Tags: linux, load-balancing, haproxy

I would like to make deny for specific domains + path preferably using maps or text file in haproxy.
For example, I would like to define file with domain:

```
example.com/test-path
example2.com/another-path
etc.
```

And do deny for each domain + url in the file. Is such a configuration possible in haproxy?
I know i can do that using simple acl:

```
acl block_example_path path_beg /test-path
acl block_example_domain hdr(host) -i example.com

acl block_example2_path path_beg /another-path
acl block_example2_domain hdr(host) -i example2.com

http-request deny if block_example_domain block_example_path
http-request deny if block_example2_domain block_example2_path
```

But potentially I will have a lot of these domains, which will cause a terrible problem to keep it in the config file.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this using a defined domain+path file?